# Не удаётся настроить среду разработки react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mobile-development, mobile

Дело в том что у меня стоит виндовс 7 . Пытался установить node.js - говорит что он работает только на виндовс 8.1 и выше следовательно не получается работать с npm ... что делать как все это заменить чтоб можно было установить expo  и начать работу

Comment: боюсь, придется переезжать